# How to create a listener for the boolean variable?

Tags: android

I want the video to stop when the screen is scrolled up.
I use addOnScrollListener for this.

```
  public boolean scrolldurum;

      rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int  newState) {
                   // mScrollState = scrollState;
                    if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE  ) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"scrol stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        scrolldurum = false;
                        Log.e("scrolldurumburcu", String.valueOf(scrolldurum));


                    }
                    if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING  ) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"scrol START",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        scrolldurum = true;
                        Log.e("scrolldurumburcu", String.valueOf(scrolldurum));


                }
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

My boolean variable is true when the screen scrolls, and false when it stops.
But the video stop code works only in onBindViewHolder.

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final KelimelerAdapterx.CardTasarimTutucu holder, int position) {
            final Kelimeler kelime = kelimelerListe.get(position);

            holder.textViewIngilizce.setText(kelime.getAkis());
            holder.textViewTurkce.setText(kelime.getLikebtn());


if (scrolldurum = true){
    Log.e("xaxaxaxax", String.valueOf(scrolldurum));
    holder.videoView.pause();


}
            if (scrolldurum = false){
                Log.e("xaxaxaxax", String.valueOf(scrolldurum));

            }
            holder.videoView.setErrorTracker(new SimpleVideoView.VideoPlaybackErrorTracker() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaybackError(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //   Snackbar.make(holder.videoView, "Uh oh, error playing!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                    holder.videoView.start("https://goldgym.pro/imga/"+holder.textViewTurkce.getText().toString());
                    holder. videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if ( holder.videoView.isPlaying()) {
                                holder.videoView.pause();

                            }
                            else{
                                holder.videoView.play();
                            }


                        }
                    });
                }
            });

          holder.videoView.start("https://goldgym.pro/imga/"+holder.textViewTurkce.getText().toString());


            holder. videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    if ( holder.videoView.isPlaying()) {
                        Log.e("scrolldurumburcussss", String.valueOf(scrolldurum));

                        holder.videoView.pause();
                    } else {
                        holder.videoView.play();

                    }

                }

            });

        }
```

My boolean variable needs a listener.
How can I do that.
if you want to review my full code.
https://gist.github.com/prensmiskin/161741f6e497a9d624258bedbddfd9d8

[image: gif]

Comment: If you already made a scroll listener to change the boolean, and since you say it works. What is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hello Hasan, thank you for my answer.
addOnScrollListener is connected to recyclerview.
videoview is connected to the adapter.
So I can't write the video stop code inside the addOnScrollListener.
So I need a listener to get the boolean response of addOnScrollListener.